# Android -urlConnection.getInputStream() fails - InputStream stays null

Tags: android, json, null, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to retrieve JSON data from the Google Directions Server in Android. But getting the inputstream fails and an exception is thrown. I get the error message ,,null" and that the inputstream is null.

What am I doing wrong with the HTTP connection? The URL is working on my browser.

```
     private String doRequest() {
    String response = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    URL url = null;
    String queryString ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.71926430971954,-74.26603317260742&destination=40.74309523218185," +
            "-74.24732208251953&sensor=false&mode=walking&alternatives=true&key=AIzaSyASF2b0E0HHilJL5I936vqRbiBjM5XuPRA";


    try {
        url = new URL(queryString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            if (response == null)
                builder.append("Response is null.");
            if (url == null)
                builder.append("url is null.");
            if (urlConnection == null)
                builder.append("UrlConnection is null.");
            if (in == null)
                builder.append("Inputstream is null.");

            return builder.toString() +e.getMessage();
        }


    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    if (response == null)
    {
        return "sorry, response is null. At least it passed the exceptions.";
    }
    return response;
}
```

---

EDIT:

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoguz.png)

---

EDIT 2:

Okay, I've tried a mix of every ones suggestions. Now when I execute the code nothing happens. I can't open a dialog, so I don't know what problem it is this time.

```
public void getJSON(View v)
{
   AsyncTask<String, Void, String>hello = new GetData(this).execute(queryString);
}
```

import android.app.Dialog;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.net.http.HttpsConnection;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

import android.view.View;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

(public class GetData extends AsyncTask)

{

```
private Exception exception;
public String response;
private Context context;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
public GetData(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
{
    this.response = doRequest(urls[0]);

    return response;
}

protected void onPostExecute() {
    // TODO: check this.exception
    // TODO: do something with the feed

    if (this.exception != null && response != null)
    {
        getDialog(getResponse(), context).show();
    }
    else
    {
        getDialog("sorry" + exception.getMessage(), context).show();
    }

}

private String doRequest(String queryString) {
    String response1 = null;
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    URL url = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(queryString);
        urlConnection =(HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); // or POST
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            response1 = convertStreamToString(in);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            if (response1 == null)
                builder.append("Response is null.");
            if (url == null)
                builder.append("url is null.");
            if (urlConnection == null)
                builder.append("UrlConnection is null.");
            if (in == null)
                builder.append("Inputstream is null.");

            return builder.toString() + e.getMessage();
        }

    } 

    finally
    {
        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    if (response1 == null)
    {
        return "sorry, response is null. At least it passed the exceptions.";
    }
    return response1;
}

private String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is)
{
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}

public String getResponse()
{
    return this.response;
}


public Dialog getDialog(String string, Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(string);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();

}
```

Comment: check internet connection

Comment: Please post your import package for HttpURLConnection.

Comment: What does e.getMessage() contain?

Comment: I can surf on the virtual device and the permissions for internet on gradle are there. What else can I check?

Comment: @KarlBall import package for HttpURLConnection

Comment: I have imported the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may attempts to perform a networking operation in  doRequest() on  main thread. Run your code in AsyncTask https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
following code may help you

problem is with your onPostExecute and dialog. you should override onPostExecute and getDialog will return AlertDialog. Whenever your request is successful exception must be null. check my edited code:

```
    class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;
        public String response;
        private Context context;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

        public GetData(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            this.response = doRequest(urls[0]);

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed

            if (this.exception == null && response != null) {
                getDialog(response, context).show();
            } else {
                getDialog("sorry" + exception.getMessage(), context).show();
            }

        }

        private String doRequest(String queryString) {
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            InputStream in = null;
            URL url = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(queryString);
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); // or POST
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    response = convertStreamToString(in);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                {
                    exception = e;
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    if (response == null)
                        builder.append("Response is null.");
                    if (url == null)
                        builder.append("url is null.");
                    if (urlConnection == null)
                        builder.append("UrlConnection is null.");
                    if (in == null)
                        builder.append("Inputstream is null.");

                    return builder.toString() + e.getMessage();
                }

            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null)
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            if (response == null) {
                return "sorry, response is null. At least it passed the exceptions.";
            }
            return response;
        }

        private String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
            java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
            return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        }

       /* public String getResponse() {
            return this.response;
        }*/


        public AlertDialog getDialog(String string, Context context) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage(string);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            return builder.create();



   }
}

public void getJSON(View v)
{
   AsyncTask<String, Void, String>hello = new GetData(MainActivity.this).execute(queryString);//MainActivity will be your activity 
}
```

Comment: That's true, I tried to execute the code in the MainActivity. However, I've tried with AsyncTask now but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Karl Ball what is the problem you are facing now. Above code worked for me fine.

Comment: @Karl Ball problem is with your onPostExecute and dialog. you should override onPostExecute and getDialog will return AlertDialog. Whenever your request is successful exception must be null. check my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

First, add Internet permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then add this to your existing code:

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); // or POST
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Then check the response code :

```
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
}
```

You should also change the way you read the InputStream to something like this:

```
try {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")); 
    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
    String str;
    while (null != (str = input.readLine())) {
        strB.append(str).append("\r\n"); 
    }
    input.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link using HTTPS protocol, but you're trying to cast the connection to HTTP not HTTPS:

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Try to remove casting and do:

```
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
```

Or cast it to HTTPS:

```
urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Now the InputStream should be not null.

Regards